# join tables in RoR

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have the following two models.

```
class ResponseMap < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :response, foreign_key: 'map_id', dependent: :destroy
belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: 'Participant', foreign_key: 'reviewer_id'


class Response < ActiveRecord::Base
include ResponseAnalytic

belongs_to :response_map, class_name: 'ResponseMap', foreign_key: 'map_id'
```

I have to join these two models and find the responses given by a particular reviewer in ResponseMap such that response.map_id = responseMap.id. This is the SQL query i need to translate to an active record query for my ResponseMap model.

```
select * from response_maps as rm join responses as r on r.map_id = rm.id where rm.reviewer_id = 97
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I think `has_many :response` should be `has_many :responses`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you need to correct the association

```ruby
class ResponseMap < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :responses, foreign_key: 'map_id', dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :reviewer, class_name: 'Participant', foreign_key: 'reviewer_id'
```

If you have a `has_many` association the name should be plural.

The query

```
ResponseMap.joins(:responses).where(reviewer_id: 97)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `has_many :response` should be `has_many :responses`

Use `joins` method:

```
ResponseMap.joins(:responses).where(reviewer_id: 97)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use joins method.

```
ResponseMap.joins(:response).where('response_maps.map_id = ?', map_id)
```

This will inner join response_maps table with responses table as you want to achieve. 
Read more about joins from rails guides: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: what does where('response_maps.map_id = ?', map_id) mean?

Comment: this returns ResponseMap records matching to given `map_id`. We tell rails that we need map_id matching to our given map_id, for example:

Comment: where('response_maps.map_id = ?', 10) will return response_maps whose map_id values are 10